# c++ STL containor stores a class that overloads operator =

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, std, stdvector

source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int value;
    A& operator = (const A& from) { value=from.value; return *this; }
    A(std::string a_name, int a_val) { name=a_name; value=a_val; }
};

int main()
{    
    std::vector<A> va;
    va.push_back(A("first",1));
    va.push_back(A("second",2));

    std::vector<A> vb;
    vb.push_back(A("third",3));
    vb.push_back(A("fourth",4));

    va = vb;   //point T

    return 0;

}
```

At **point T**, **std::vector<A>::operator=** calls each stored member's overloaded operator **A::operator=**

the result is not i wanted.

my expected result is that:
after **point T**, the **va**'s member is exactly same **vb** like
**va[0].name** is "third" and **va[1].value** is "fourth".

but the result is only copy the value (Because the **A::operator=** copys only **A::value**)

in my project, the **A::operator=** can't be changed because it already used many other codes.
but i want use also **std::container::operator=**. not using Specified Copy Functions.

which way can do this?

Comment: The class `A` has a poorly written constructor (no initializer list), so I wouldn't say that maintaining this class sounds like a worthwhile thing to do. If this is any indication, then the codebase you're working with is probably of low quality throughout and could benefit from a rewrite.

Comment: If your assignment operator does a partial copy then it's a good suggestion that your original design was flawed.

Comment: It really sounds that your current `operator=` needs to be renamed something like `setValueFrom()`. You can try abusing operator overloading but if you get a fundamental thing like assignment wrong, the language bites back. - Try disabling `operator=` for this class (by inheriting from a non-assignable base class), so you can find all places where it is used?

Answer (score 4):

It is **your** responsibility to implement the assignment operator in such a fashion that after an assignment `a = b;` the object `a` has the same semantics as object `b`.

If you really cannot do that, then perhaps you can rely on the implicitly-defined copy constructor:

```
std::vector<A>(vb).swap(va);
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//    copy of vb
```

Comment: +1: Maintaining explicitly specified assignment operators is your problem

Comment: mmm i understood the **operator=** means 'make same left to right'. i need refactoring my whole code to: Replace every **A::operator=** that means partial copy to Specified Copy Functions. And using **A::operator=** only that means 'make same left to right'. Thanks for your advice and i'm sorry my short english...